# Asynchronously Load the Contents of a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm looking for a way to asynchronously load the contents of a whole div. I'd like to delay the loading of everything in the div. Also, assume that each div has an image in it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

```
(function($){

var paginate = {
    startPos: function(pageNumber, perPage) {
        // determine what array position to start from
        // based on current page and # per page
        return pageNumber * perPage;
    },

    getPage: function(items, startPos, perPage) {
        // declare an empty array to hold our page items
        var page = [];

        // only get items after the starting position
        items = items.slice(startPos, items.length);

        // loop remaining items until max per page
        for (var i=0; i < perPage; i++) {
            page.push(items[i]); }

        return page;
    },

    totalPages: function(items, perPage) {
        // determine total number of pages
        return Math.ceil(items.length / perPage);
    },

    createBtns: function(totalPages, currentPage) {
        // create buttons to manipulate current page
        var pagination = $('<div class="pagination" />');

        // add a "first" button
        pagination.append('<span class="pagination-button">&laquo;</span>');

        // add pages inbetween
        for (var i=1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            // truncate list when too large
            if (totalPages > 5 && currentPage !== i) {
                // if on first two pages
                if (currentPage === 1 || currentPage === 2) {
                    // show first 5 pages
                    if (i > 5) continue;
                // if on last two pages
                } else if (currentPage === totalPages || currentPage === totalPages - 1) {
                    // show last 5 pages
                    if (i < totalPages - 4) continue;
                // otherwise show 5 pages w/ current in middle
                } else {
                    if (i < currentPage - 2 || i > currentPage + 2) {
                        continue; }
                }
            }

            // markup for page button
            var pageBtn = $('<span class="pagination-button page-num" />');

            // add active class for current page
            if (i == currentPage) {
                pageBtn.addClass('active'); }

            // set text to the page number
            pageBtn.text(i);

            // add button to the container
            pagination.append(pageBtn);
        }

        // add a "last" button
        pagination.append($('<span class="pagination-button">&raquo;</span>'));

        return pagination;
    },

    createPage: function(items, currentPage, perPage) {
        // remove pagination from the page
        $('.pagination').remove();

        // set context for the items
        var container = items.parent(),
            // detach items from the page and cast as array
            items = items.detach().toArray(),
            // get start position and select items for page
            startPos = this.startPos(currentPage - 1, perPage),
            page = this.getPage(items, startPos, perPage);

        // loop items and readd to page
        $.each(page, function(){
            // prevent empty items that return as Window
            if (this.window === undefined) {
                container.append($(this)); }
        });

        // prep pagination buttons and add to page
        var totalPages = this.totalPages(items, perPage),
            pageButtons = this.createBtns(totalPages, currentPage);

        container.after(pageButtons);
    }
};

// stuff it all into a jQuery method!
$.fn.paginate = function(perPage) {
    var items = $(this);

    // default perPage to 5
    if (isNaN(perPage) || perPage === undefined) {
        perPage = 5; }

    // don't fire if fewer items than perPage
    if (items.length <= perPage) {
        return true; }

    // ensure items stay in the same DOM position
    if (items.length !== items.parent()[0].children.length) {
        items.wrapAll('<div class="pagination-items" />');
    }

    // paginate the items starting at page 1
    paginate.createPage(items, 1, perPage);

    // handle click events on the buttons
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination-button', function(e) {
        // get current page from active button
        var currentPage = parseInt($('.pagination-button.active').text(), 10),
            newPage = currentPage,
            totalPages = paginate.totalPages(items, perPage),
            target = $(e.target);

        // get numbered page
        newPage = parseInt(target.text(), 10);
        if (target.text() == '«') newPage = 1;
        if (target.text() == '»') newPage = totalPages;

        // ensure newPage is in available range
        if (newPage > 0 && newPage <= totalPages) {
            paginate.createPage(items, newPage, perPage); }
    });
};

})(jQuery);

$('.article-loop').paginate(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `load()` function of JQuery to execute a callback function once a certain element has completely been loaded.

For example, if you have three `<div>` elements like so:

```
<body>
<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
</body>
```

You can load them sequentially by changing the HTML to:

```
<div id="first">First</div>
```

and then using JQuery to append the other `div`s once the previous one has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").load(function() {
    $("body").append($("<div></div>").attr({id: "second"}).text("Second"));
    $("#second").load(function() {
      $("body").append($("<div></div>").attr({id: "third"}).text("Third"));
    });
  });
});
```

There are cleaner ways to write this logic, but this is just enough to get the point across.

Comment: I don't think this will work. DIVs don't get loaded asynchronously.`$(document).ready()` doesn't run its code until all the DIVs are loaded.