# jQuery .load() failure

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run an answer I found at the following link:
[Asynchronously Load the Contents of a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580373/asynchronously-load-the-contents-of-a-div#)

But when I do, I get errors that I don't quite understand.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").load(function() {
    $("body").append($("<div></div>").attr({
      id: "second"
    }).text("Second"));
    $("#second").load(function() {
      $("body").append($("<div></div>").attr({
        id: "third"
      }).text("Third"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="#first">First</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The error I get back from Chrome is extensive. But here's the highlights:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (temp.html:6)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error when opening new foundation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat)

Comment: `$("#first")` does not equal `<div class="#first">`

Comment: There's no `load` event for `<div>`. Only elements that fill themselves in from external resources, like `<img>` and `<script>` trigger the `load` event.

Answer (score 9):

This error might be caused by jquery event aliases like `.error`, `.load` or `.unload`. These are deprecated since `jQuery 1.8`. You need to replace them with `.on()` to register listeners instead. Example:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  ...
});
```

becomes:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
 ...
});
```

So try using with `.on()`

Comment: Thanks!  The errors are gone, but only the first "First" div appears.  The other div's aren't created.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is resolved by using:

```
$("#first").on('load', function() {
  *code to be executed*
}
```

`.load` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8

The second issue you mention that only the first div is created happens because you are trying to execute the next function to create the third div when the second div is loaded but in reality the second div is not loaded since you are appending it so no load is occurring in this case.

You can just append one after the other and they will appear in order assuming that is what you are trying to do.