# jQuery.Deferred exception: e.indexOf is not a function after updating jquery.min.js to latest

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mcustomscrollbar

I am using jQuery 1.12.0 and everything is working well. For optimization I have upgraded to jQuery 3.4.1 and now my slider is not working. It is giving me an error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: e.indexOf is not a function k.fn.load@https://website/js/jquery.min.js?v=1.76.1:2:83687
>   D/<@https://website/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:4:20503

```js
$(elementID).mCustomScrollbar({
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: false
  },
  theme: "rounded",
  scrollEasing: "easeOut",
  moveDragger: true,
  mouseWheel: {
    scrollAmount: 200
  },
  keyboard: {
    enable: 1
  },
  keyboard: {
    scrollAmount: 200
  },
  keyboard: {
    scrollType: "stepless"
  },
  contentTouchScroll: 200,
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  alwaysTriggerOffsets: true,
  advanced: {
    updateOnBrowserResize: true,
    updateOnContentResize: true,
    autoScrollOnFocus: true
  }
});
```

when i was using old version of minified, everything was good. As per the other link, it is suggesting that i am using `$(window).load` but i don't have that in my code.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45974735/3768239

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error when opening new foundation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat)

Comment: what i don't understand is where is that $(window).load() is. In my website js, no load function are written and if it is in customScrollbar or min.js then do i need to fix it.